# Canonical example of Fatou Lemma

Tags: probability-theory

I'm following Sidney Resnick's *A probability path*. On section 5.3, he gives the so-called "canonical (counter-)example" of Fatou's Lemma. The example is as follows:

Consider the probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the usual Lebesgue-measure. Define $X_n = n^2 \cdot 1_{(0,1/n)}$. Then, we have $X_n\to 0$ and $E[X_n] = n^2 \cdot 1/n = n \to \infty$.

Now, I'm asked to consider a similar example, with $Y_n = n \cdot 1_{(0,1/\sqrt{n})}$. In this case, we have $Y_n \to 0$. I'm supposed to show that $E[Y_n] \to 0$. But I don't understand why the following reasoning is not valid:

$$E[Y_n] = n \cdot 1/\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n} \to \infty.$$

Comment: $E[Y_n] \to \infty$ is correct.

Comment: I understand the problem, now. It seems I have an older version of the book with an error here.